# Getting positions from Collider2D array

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to get enemies positions from Collider2D array to knockback them based on player location. I found a basic attack tutorial without knockback but can't figure it out myself. Here's the code:

```
            if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
        {
            Debug.Log("Hit!");
            Collider2D[] enemiesToDamage = Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll(attackPos.position, attackRange, whatisEnemies);
            for (int i = 0; i < enemiesToDamage.Length; i++)
            {
                enemiesToDamage[i].GetComponent<Enemy>().TakeDamage(playerBasicAttackDamage);

                enemiesPositions[i] = enemiesToDamage[i].GetComponent<Transform>().position;
                
                knockBackDir[i] = (enemiesPositions[i] - this.transform.position).normalized;

                enemiesToDamage[i].GetComponent<Enemy>().EnemyKnockBack(knockBackDir[i]);
            }
        }
```

It doesn't show problems in Visual Studio but in Unity it tells me about indexoutofrangeexception when trying to run this line:

```
enemiesPositions[i] = enemiesToDamage[i].GetComponent<Transform>().position;
```

I'm sure I'm not getting it right so any help would be much appreciated.

In another script it goes like this:

```
    public void EnemyKnockBack(Vector3 dir)
{
    rb.velocity = new Vector3(dir.x * 50, dir.y * 50, 0);
}
```

Comment: Can you add what **enemiesPositions** variable include. Probably **enemiesPositions** array/list length is shorter than **enemiesToDamage** array/list. That can be the cause of problem.

Comment: It includes anything inside Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll, i.e. 1 enemy. I managed to solve it with this foreach method but want to know what's wrong with my previous one because the code is identical besides working with arrays ([i]'s).

Comment: When you use foreach, how did you access to the content(s) of **enemiesPositions** list/array?

Comment: @SeLeCtRa, added it as an answer, you can look if you want. Thanks)

Answer (score 1):

You probably never initialized the enemiesPositions Array. This should probably do the trick.

```
enemiesPosition = new Vector3[enemiesToDamage.Length];
```

Comment: Sadly, didn't change nothing, the error is still there. Strange, because I did exactly the same thing in foreach loop (will add as an answer right now).

Comment: @Fabian Friedrich enemiesPosition is not an array, it is a List<T> from System.Colllections.Generic Class. In question body, he trying to change the value at index. You can't do it in arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Changed the code to use foreach loop and it seems to be working well now. Not sure what exactly changed:

```
                Collider2D[] enemiesToDamage = Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll(attackPos.position, attackRange, whatisEnemies);
            foreach (Collider2D enemy in enemiesToDamage)
            {
                enemy.GetComponent<Enemy>().TakeDamage(playerBasicAttackDamage);
                enemyPosition = enemy.GetComponent<Transform>().position;
                knockBackDir2 = (enemyPosition - this.transform.position).normalized;
                enemy.GetComponent<Enemy>().EnemyKnockBack(knockBackDir2);

            }
```

Comment: So where did you initialize your enemiesPositions array in question? Probably that was the problem.